# Generating headlines before reference types in sorted bibliography (CSL)

Tags: pandoc, pdflatex, csl, pandoc-citeproc

Recently I have found a [tip](https://libguides.graduateinstitute.ch/ld.php?content_id=32744969) that allows for sorting CSL-generated bibliography by reference type in PDF output. In my example, I applied this tip accordingly:

```
<macro name="sort-key">
<choose>
  <if type="book chapter report" match="any">
    <text value="1"/>
  </if>
  <else-if type="article-journal article-magazine article-newspaper" match="any">
    <text value="2"/>
  </else-if>
  <else-if type="webpage post-weblog" match="any">
    <text value="3"/>
  </else-if>
  <else-if type="software" match="any">
    <text value="4"/>
  </else-if>
  <else-if type="motion-picture" match="any">
    <text value="5"/>
  </else-if>    
  <else>
    <text value="6"/>
  </else>
</choose>
</macro>

...

<bibliography et-al-min="5" et-al-use-first="1" entry-spacing="0" hanging-indent="true">
  <sort>
    <key macro="sort-key"/>
    <key macro="author-bibliography"/>
    <key variable="title"/>
  </sort>

...
</bibliography>
```

Still, I have a question: is it possible, in such a sorted bibliography, to attribute named headlines to the following reference types without having to produce a Word output and putting the headlines directly? I use the newest Pandoc with `pdflatex` output and couldn't find any accurate solutions on the Web. While I acknowledge that it is possible to use the `multiple-bibliography.lua` filter, this is not the case because I'd like to print output using one bibliography file, with headlines added before each `text value`.

Comment: You could use a filter to modify the references after applying the pandoc-citeproc filter. the cite-key is retained as the identifier of the bibliography item, so one could use that to lookup the original reference in the metadata. Insert a header every time the type changes. You'll want to pass the bibliography via `pandoc --metadata-file <(pandoc-citeproc -y YOUR_BIB.bib)` instead using the usual methods, as that will make it easy to query it in a filter.

Comment: @tarleb Thank you for the response, but I had already converted the bibliography to CSL JSON output. My question rather concerns if the references are sorted with the code above, it is possible to print different headlines before each group of selected reference types. Nowadays, ```text value``` fields in CSL don't allow for putting the headlines in; they only specify the order of groups containing specific document types. The question has been slightly edited.

Comment: The above still applies even with a CSL JSON bibliography. What I'm suggesting is to iterate over the bibliography in *pandoc's internal format*, then adding headers in there whenever a new group starts. The information to map from the generated bibliography entry to the input JSON entry is all there. Run `pandoc --to=native --filter=pandoc-citeproc` on your document to see how the document is represented internally.

Comment: @tarleb Oh, I see! I typed into the command line ```pandoc -f markdown -t latex -s markdown-file.md -o tex-file.txt  --filter=pandoc-citeproc --metadata-file=bibliography.json```, pasted latex sections and run ```pdflatex tex-file.txt```; all worked! But maybe someone has a simpler answer?

Comment: Good to see that you found a working solution! However, it is still not quite what I have in mind. I'm not talking about modifying the output, but to use a filter to modify pandoc's internal (*native*) format. You'd have to write quite a bit of Lua, so whether that would be easier than manually editing the result is fairly subjective. If you are going with manual postprocessing, you could use `diff` and `patch` to (semi-)automate the LaTeX-editing step.